# How should I arrange my javascript files?

Tags: file-structure

I think this is best described using an image.
[image]

So it dawned on me that perhaps this isn't the best or most logical way to  organise files.
The way it is currently, as you can see is just a dumping ground. The only reason `complexify` has it's own folder is that it's a submodule in Git.

So should I be using a `/lib` folder with `jquery` & `jqueryui` and perhaps a `/plugins` with all the plugins in? Where would my files live?

Are there any accepted practises for file structure in this situation where you have a core library, a number of plugins and then some of your own code?

*PS, I realised just now I have two copies of jQueryUI.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, put 3rd party not-your-code files in directories so you can keep them separate from your files. A common naming convention is 'lib' or 'libs' with each 3rd party library in its own sub-directory (so you can directly update the files from their own source repo with a little more control).

You can put your files anywhere you like then, usually in the root.

Comment: Great, so I'm thinking along the right lines :)

Comment: +1 Exactly. Organize JS just like the rest of your code.